# Airflow inside docker doesn't see new files in /var catalog

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, airflow

I'm running airflow webserver inside Docker to run some python scripts, but when some file in /var catalog is created after webserver was started, these python scripts inside DAG-s simply doesn't see any changes, for example, a set of commands produces that results (everything is done inside docker container):

`touch /var/test/teestfile`

and after that, python from shell:

`os.listdir('/var/test')` returns list
`['testfile']`

python script inside airflow dag:

`os.listdir('/var/test')` returns list `[]`

If something was initially in var directory, for example, volume attached from the host with docker.sock, or system files, both shell, and airflow see that files.
Sorry for my English, or if something isn't clear, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Docker containers have they own file system. You have to mount a volume to exchange files with the host.

Comment: I know, but everything is encapsulated inside docker, airflow is inside this container as well /var directory also is from the container, not the host